# Cannot connect to Wi-Fi network after Windows 10 upgrade

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-10, router, windows-10-upgrade

I have a TP-LINK router v TL-WR841N I've been using for the last year. The Windows 10 installed on my PC has just got upgraded (force-upgraded) to the latest version I guess. After this upgrade I cannot connect to my home Wi-Fi network for some reason. It is visible, however it says "Cannot connect to the network" when I try to connect. I tried to connect to the network with my smartphone, and it worked alright.

What I tried so far:

1. "Forget" the network and connect to it again.
2. Reboot my laptop and the router.
3. Disable antivirus.
4. Disable Brandmauer.

Nothing really helped. Any ideas?

Comment: I currently have the same problem (and could not fix it yet) with a static IP address on Windows 10. Setting one in the control panel or even using the `net` tool in command prompt does not work, only DHCP is working. Smartphones always use DHCP, when you don't tell them something else. What do you use, static IP or DHCP?

Comment: @sigalor I had to connect via a wire to post this question. Not sure what happened. It might have updated some software while connected, but this morning it managed to connect to the wi-fi. Windows and router were not rebooted.

Answer (score 0):

The most recent windows updates seemed to have caused a hot of problems with network drivers. Please double check that the driver running your antenna has not changed to a generic Microsoft driver. If so, disable that driver using the device manager, then obtain a good driver from the manufacturer's web site (either by using cat5 to the system, or copying to USB from another system) and install it on the computer having problems. Reboot afterwards, and your network should start functioning again.

Comment: I had to connect via a wire to post this question. Not sure what happened. It might have updated some software while connected, but this morning it managed to connect to the wi-fi. Windows and router were not rebooted.

Answer (score -2):

Right-Click on the Wifi/Network icon in the taskbar and select "Troubleshoot Problems"

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Answers are intended to be definitive solutions.  Diagnostic suggestions are more appropriate as a comment, which requires a little more rep.